# Reading selection from picker SwiftUI

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui, picker

I'm creating a picker in which a food product is selected from the array `productList` of type `Product` and I'm trying to create text boxes that output every variable stored in whichever product was selected. However, although the code is successfully built, the picker won't allow the user to make a selection. How can I fix this?

This is my code:

```
struct AddView : View {
    @State var selectFood = 0
    @ObservedObject var database : Database
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Picker(selection: $selectFood, label: Text("What did you eat?")
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .foregroundColor(.white))
            {
                ForEach(database.productList) { (productList: Product) in
                    Text(productList.name)
                }
            }
            .pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
            
            Spacer(minLength: 100)
            
            ZStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(width: 350, height: 90, alignment: .center)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .opacity(0.25)
                    .offset(y: 40)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                Text("Calories: \(database.productList[selectFood].calories)")
                
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
            Text("Enter")
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding(.horizontal, 50)
    }
}
```

This is the code where the array is stored:

```
struct Product : Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name : String
    var calories : Double
    var protein : Double
    var carbs : Double
    var fats : Double
    var weight : Double

    
}

class Database : ObservableObject{
    
    @Published var productList = [Product]()
    
    init() {
        self.productList = [
            Product(name: "Apple", calories: 52, protein: 0.3, carbs: 14, fats: 0.2, weight: 80),
            Product(name: "Avocado", calories: 160, protein: 2, carbs: 9, fats: 15, weight: 600),
            Product(name: "Banana", calories: 89, protein: 1.1, carbs: 23, fats: 0.3, weight: 120),
            Product(name: "Broccoli", calories: 34, protein: 2.8, carbs: 5, fats: 0.4, weight: 225),
            Product(name: "Burger", calories: 264, protein: 13, carbs: 30, fats: 10, weight: 110),
            Product(name: "Carrot", calories: 41, protein: 0.9, carbs: 10, fats: 0.2, weight: 61),
            Product(name: "Cheerios", calories: 379, protein: 6, carbs: 83, fats: 5, weight: 40),
            Product(name: "Cherry", calories: 50, protein: 1, carbs: 12, fats: 0.3, weight: 5),
            Product(name: "Chicken Nuggets", calories: 302, protein: 16, carbs: 15, fats: 20, weight: 16),
            Product(name: "Cocoa Pops", calories: 389, protein: 5, carbs: 85, fats: 2.9, weight: 45),
            Product(name: "Corn Flakes", calories: 357, protein: 8, carbs: 84, fats: 0.4, weight: 45),
            Product(name: "Crunchy Nuts", calories: 402, protein: 6, carbs: 82, fats: 5, weight: 45),
            Product(name: "Eggs", calories: 196, protein: 14, carbs: 0.8, fats: 15, weight: 60),
            Product(name: "Fries", calories: 312, protein: 3.4, carbs: 43, fats: 15, weight: 100),
            Product(name: "Froasted Flakes", calories: 369, protein: 4, carbs: 89, fats: 1.7, weight: 45),
    ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type of selection should be same as type of Picker data block id or tag, so if you want selected index, then it should be like

```
struct AddView : View {
    @State var selectFood = 0
    @ObservedObject var database : Database

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Picker(selection: $selectFood, label: Text("What did you eat?")
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .foregroundColor(.white))
            {
                ForEach(database.productList.indices, id: \.self) { i in  // << here
                    Text(database.productList[i].name)    // << and here 
                }
            }
            .pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())

  // ... other code
```